# How to marshal xml with optional tags in Go

Tags: xml, go

The code for my problem is here: https://play.golang.org/p/X8Ey2hqmxL

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Carriage struct {
    MainCarriage interface{} `xml:"mainCarriage"`
}

type SeaCarriage struct {
    Sea          xml.Name `xml:"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012 sea"`
    LoadFactor   float64  `xml:"loadFactor,attr"`
    SeaCargoType string   `xml:"seaCargoType,attr"`
}

type RoadCarriage struct {
    Road xml.Name `xml:"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012 road"`
}

func main() {

    fr := Carriage{
        MainCarriage: SeaCarriage{
            LoadFactor:   70,
            SeaCargoType: "Container",
        },
    }
    xmlBlob, err := xml.MarshalIndent(&fr, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(xmlBlob))
}
```

I need to marshall data into SOAP xml. I'm currently getting this result:

```
<Carriage>
    <mainCarriage loadFactor="70" seaCargoType="Container">
        <sea xmlns="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012"></sea>
    </mainCarriage>
</Carriage>
```

But I need this result:

```
<Carriage>
    <mainCarriage>
        <sea xmlns="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012" loadFactor="70" seaCargoType="Container"></sea>
    </mainCarriage>
</Carriage>
```

No matter what I try I cannot marshal the structs so that the loadFactor and the seaCargoType are attrs of the `sea` tag.

The Carriage struct takes an empty interface because depending on the shipment type the tag should be either sea or road but never both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `>.` after `mainCarriage` field tag to indicate that you want to put contents of the field inside `mainCarriage` tag. Change the name of `Sea` field to `XMLName` as required by marshaller.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Carriage struct {
    MainCarriage interface{} `xml:"mainCarriage>."`
}

type SeaCarriage struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name `xml:"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012 sea"`
    LoadFactor   float64  `xml:"loadFactor,attr"`
    SeaCargoType string   `xml:"seaCargoType,attr"`
}

type RoadCarriage struct {
    Road xml.Name `xml:"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/standard/2012 road"`
}

func main() {

    fr := Carriage{
        MainCarriage: SeaCarriage{
            LoadFactor:   70,
            SeaCargoType: "Container",
        },
    }
    xmlBlob, err := xml.MarshalIndent(&fr, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(xmlBlob))
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pDoyqzrQtX)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. The `>.` was the missing piece and something I hadn't seen before.